# Remover texto "body" del footer en editor WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Estoy trabajando con un ckeditor, y todo funciona bien, pero me gustaría saber, como se pueden borrar la etiqueta de body para que no parezca una vez que empiece a escribir.

[image: eliminar etiqueta body al comenzar a utilizar el editor]

Agrego mi código

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <textarea id="ckeditorEmail" name="ckeditor1" rows="5"></textarea>
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 10px">
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" name="archivo" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile04">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile04">Selecciona un archivo</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-w">
        <div class="actions-right">
            <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="os-icon os-icon-mail-18"></i><span>Enviar Mensaje</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y mi javascript es así

```
if ($('#ckeditor1').length) {
  CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor1');
}

if (typeof CKEDITOR !== 'undefined') {
  CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
  if ($('#ckeditorEmail').length) {
    CKEDITOR.config.uiColor = '#ffffff';
     CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink']];
    CKEDITOR.config.height = 110;
    CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor1');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola! Nos ayudaría mucho si incluyes el código de como lo estás insertando.

Comment: He agregado mi codigo, gracias

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028379/ckeditor-removing-html-and-body-tags

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió agradecería que la marques como respuesta aprovada :)

Answer (score 1):

Las propiedades `config.removePlugins` & `config.resize_enabled` tienen que ser configuradas:

```
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
config.resize_enabled = false;
```

Por alguna razón el fragmento no funciona en SO, pero lo puedes ver funcionando en JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7a9vr8tw/

```js
if ($('#ckeditor1').length) {
  CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor1');
}

if (typeof CKEDITOR !== 'undefined') {
  CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
  if ($('#ckeditorEmail').length) {
    CKEDITOR.config.uiColor = '#ffffff';
     CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink']];
    CKEDITOR.config.height = 110;
    
    CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
  CKEDITOR.config.resize_enabled = false;
    CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor1');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.2/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.2/adapters/jquery.js"></script>



<div class="col-sm-12">
    <textarea id="ckeditorEmail" name="ckeditor1" rows="5"></textarea>
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 10px">
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" name="archivo" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile04">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile04">Selecciona un archivo</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-w">
        <div class="actions-right">
            <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="os-icon os-icon-mail-18"></i><span>Enviar Mensaje</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```